# What is the best way to go about conditional rendering in the case of very similar components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, higher-order-components, conditional-rendering

I render different landing pages based on whether the user is a professor, student, or not logged in. The landing pages are very similar; the only difference is the buttons displayed. I know I can go around this using inline conditions or simple if-else statements. However, I was wondering what the *best* practices are to implement conditional rendering in this case. I know higher order components (HOCs) can help but I was not sure if they are overkill in this particular case.

To be on the same page, here are the different Landing components that I currently render using if-else statements.

Landing.js (unlogged users):

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { compose } from 'recompose';
import { withEither } from '../../helpers/withEither';
import LandingStudent from './LandingStudent';
import LandingProfessor from './LandingProfessor';
import './Landing.css';

const Landing = ({ history }) => {
  return(
    <div className="header">
      <div className="text-box">
        <h1 className="header-primary">
          <span className="header-primary-main">
            QME
          </span>
          <span className="header-primary-sub">
            the best way to ask questions
          </span>
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Landing;
```

LandingProfessor.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import './Landing.css';

const LandingProfessor = ({ history }) => {
  return(
    <div className="header">
      <div className="text-box">
        <h1 className="header-primary">
          <span className="header-primary-main">
            QME
          </span>
          <span className="header-primary-sub">
            the best way to ask questions
          </span>
        </h1>
        <RaisedButton
          className="btn-animated btn-landing"
          label="Create Class"
          onClick={() => history.push('/courses/new')}
        />
        <RaisedButton
          className="btn-animated btn-landing"
          label="Dashboard"
          onClick={() => history.push('/courses')}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default withRouter(LandingProfessor);
```

LandingStudent.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import './Landing.css';

const Landing = ({ history }) => {
  return(
    <div className="header">
      <div className="text-box">
        <h1 className="header-primary">
          <span className="header-primary-main">
            QME
          </span>
          <span className="header-primary-sub">
            the best way to ask questions
          </span>
        </h1>
        <RaisedButton
          className="btn-animated btn"
          label="Join Class"
          onClick={() => history.push('/courses/join')}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default withRouter(Landing);
```

Comment: Using `if`/`else` or a `switch` seems reasonable. What specific concerns do you have? I would put off worrying about "too much re-rendering" until you can measure and prove that switching between these components is actually a performance problem.

Comment: @RossAllen My concern is I do the same thing with my Header component and possibly other components in the future. I was wondering if there's a way to do this without having to repeat the same if/else or switch statements and make my code as dry as possible.

Comment: Can you add some of the conditional rendering that has you concerned or open another question with that code and mention me?

Answer (score 0):

A 'trick' could be to append a className on the root div for landscape, namely 'student' 'professor' or 'logout' and use css display: none to hide unwanted items in each scenarios

Another approach would be to keep your 3 components but delegate all the rendering to a common 'LandingRenderer' component that would accept boolean properties like 'showJoinClassButton' 'showCreateButtonButton' etc.

Then your 3 components render would look like domething like this

```
LandingProfessor: (props) => (
    <LandingRenderer 
        showJoinClassButton={false} 
        showCreateClassButton={true} 
        ... 
        {...props} />
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would opt for composition over inheritance here, meaning create many reusable components and compose your top-level components with those reusable ones rather than make your top-level components inherit from one common component type. If you follow the latter approach, you might end up with a laundry list of props that I argue is questionably better than what you have right now.

To start, you could componentize your header:

Header.js

```
export default function Header(props) {
  return (
    <h1 className="header-primary">
      {props.children}
    </h1>
  );
}

Header.Main = function HeaderMain(props) {
  return (
    <span className="header-primary-main">
      {props.children}
    </span>
  );
};

Header.Sub = function HeaderSub(props) {
  return (
    <span className="header-primary-sub">
      {props.children}
    </span>
  );
};
```

and use it in Landing.js:

```
import Header from './Header.js';

const Landing = ({ history }) => {
  return(
    <div className="header">
      <div className="text-box">
        <Header>
          <Header.Main>QME</Header.Main>
          <Header.Sub>the best way to ask questions</Header.Sub>
        </Header>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think hoc in this particular case is an overkill.
I think whenever you can use hoc for better readability and useability, use it.

Using some of [recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose) hocs (you should install recompose: `npm install recompose`)

```
export const renderByConditions = (...conditions) => compose(
  ...conditions.map(condition =>
    branch(condition[0], (condition[1] && renderComponent(condition[1])) || renderNothing, condition[2] && renderComponent(condition[2]))
  )
)
```

You should pass arrays with the signature:

[`condition`, `left` (if the condition is true), `right` (else)]

```
condition - (ownProps) => youCondition
left - Component | empty
right - Component | empty
```

when left is empty - if the condition is true, it will render null.

when right is empty - if the condition is not true, it will render the component we wrapped

Then you can use the hoc:

```
renderByConditions(
  [props => props.landing, props => <Landing {...props}/>],
  [props => props.proffesor, LandingProfessor],
  [props => props.student, LandingStudent],
  [Component => Component, DefaultComponent]
)
```

I would reccommend start using recompose hocs, they are great!